# Why do restitution values less than one still cause infinite bouncing in Box2D?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, box2d

I'm currently trying to implement basketball bouncing into my game using Box2d (jBox2d technically), but I'm a bit confused about restitution.

While trying to create the ball in the testbed first, I've run into infinite bouncing, as described [in this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48470/ball-bouncing-infinitely-and-constantly), however obviously not using my own implementation.

The Box2d manual describes restitution as follows:

> Restitution is used to make objects bounce. The restitution value is usually set to be between 0 and 1. 
>   Consider dropping a ball on a table. A value of zero means the ball won't bounce. This is called an 
>   inelastic collision. A value of one means the ball's velocity will be exactly reflected. This is called a 
>   perfectly elastic collision.

My confusion lies in that I am still getting infinite bouncing with restitution values at 0.75/0.8. The same behavior can be seen [in the testbed](http://gwtbox2d.appspot.com/) under **Collision Watching -> Varying Restitution**, on the 6th and 7th balls. I believe the last one has restitution of 1, which makes sense, but I don't understand why the second to last ball bounces infinitely (as is happening with my working basketball I've created).

I am looking to understand the restitution concept more fully, as well as look for a solution to infinite bouncing with the Box2d framework. My instinct was to sleep objects that appeared to be moving in very small increments, but this seems like a misuse of the engine. Should I just work with lower restitution values altogether?

Comment: How is your question different from [that one you mentioned](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48470/ball-bouncing-infinitely-and-constantly)? It has good answers.

Comment: I'm concerned with the restitution value & bouncing specific to Box2d and its mechanics, rather than my own implementation of bouncing.

Comment: On my system 6th ball rapidly lost much of its energy, and then begun bouncing with small amplitude forever. I think, it is some kind of lose-end for box2d. May be, setting some linear damping for the ball can fix it.